# Wordpress - Custom post type archive page

Tags: wordpress

I created a custom post type using the Custom Post Type UI Plugin and made it support archives.  I have a CPT called Listing.  I am using the following function to have all the pages default to my CPT.  Everything works great except the the www.myURL.com/category page, which displays a 404 Error.
I'd like this page to display all the posts that exist as part of this CPT.

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'query_post_type');

function query_post_type($query) {
  if(is_category() || is_tag() && empty( $query->query_vars['suppress_filters'] ) ) {
    $post_type = get_query_var('post_type');
     if($post_type) {

    $post_type = $post_type; //print 'test';
}
else {
    $post_type = array('post','listing', 'nav_menu_item');  //print '2nd';
    $query->set('post_type',$post_type);
    return $query;
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you found the solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create custom post type archive page then first create this file `archive-{posttype}.php` like `archive-test.php`.

For more information follow [this link](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-a-custom-post-types-archive-page-in-wordpress/). I m sure this will work

Comment: Would this default www.myURL.com/category to a list of all my posts that are part of the custom post type?

Answer (score 0):

`www.myURL.com/category` will 404 as this URL is not available in the template hierarchy. This not only happens for `category`, but also for other archives like `author` and custom taxonomies. I know that there was a trac ticket raised for this to include index pages for this, but it was rejected.

The only way to get around this is to create a page, create a custom query on it to display what is needed and naming the page slug `category`. You just have to remember, you cannot have child pages for this page.

Comment: Is there a tutorial for this?